# Where's the explanation of the TinyMCE's vars in the WP core?

Tags: tinymce, variables, core

I am modifying my TinyMCE editor for my users, and I'm using the example [in the docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/TinyMCE) as a starting point.

```
function my_format_TinyMCE( $in ) {
    $in['remove_linebreaks'] = false;
    $in['gecko_spellcheck'] = false;
    $in['keep_styles'] = true;
    $in['accessibility_focus'] = true;
    $in['tabfocus_elements'] = 'major-publishing-actions';
    $in['media_strict'] = false;
    $in['paste_remove_styles'] = false;
    $in['paste_remove_spans'] = false;
    $in['paste_strip_class_attributes'] = 'none';
    $in['paste_text_use_dialog'] = true;
    $in['wpeditimage_disable_captions'] = true;
    $in['plugins'] = 'tabfocus,paste,media,fullscreen,wordpress,wpeditimage,wpgallery,wplink,wpdialogs,wpfullscreen';
    $in['content_css'] = get_template_directory_uri() . "/editor-style.css";
    $in['wpautop'] = true;
    $in['apply_source_formatting'] = false;
        $in['block_formats'] = "Paragraph=p; Heading 3=h3; Heading 4=h4";
    $in['toolbar1'] = 'bold,italic,strikethrough,bullist,numlist,blockquote,hr,alignleft,aligncenter,alignright,link,unlink,wp_more,spellchecker,wp_fullscreen,wp_adv ';
    $in['toolbar2'] = 'formatselect,underline,alignjustify,forecolor,pastetext,removeformat,charmap,outdent,indent,undo,redo,wp_help ';
    $in['toolbar3'] = '';
    $in['toolbar4'] = '';
    return $in;
}
```

Some of these variables are self-explanatory (e.g. *remove linebreaks*). However, not all are (e.g. *wpautop*). I can't find any documentation on this. I am looking for all explanation, not only *wpautop*.

Answer (score 1):

Some of them are TinyMCE core options. You can view them in [TinyMCE - Configuration](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration3x).

In file `/wp-includes/class-wp-editor.php` there is some explanations. Obviously its not all, but it's a start.

```
/**
 * Parse default arguments for the editor instance.
 *
 * @param string $editor_id ID for the current editor instance.
 * @param array  $settings {
 *     Array of editor arguments.
 *
 *     @type bool       $wpautop           Whether to use wpautop(). Default true.
 *     @type bool       $media_buttons     Whether to show the Add Media/other media buttons.
 *     @type string     $default_editor    When both TinyMCE and Quicktags are used, set which
 *                                         editor is shown on page load. Default empty.
 *     @type bool       $drag_drop_upload  Whether to enable drag & drop on the editor uploading. Default false.
 *                                         Requires the media modal.
 *     @type string     $textarea_name     Give the textarea a unique name here. Square brackets
 *                                         can be used here. Default $editor_id.
 *     @type int        $textarea_rows     Number rows in the editor textarea. Default 20.
 *     @type string|int $tabindex          Tabindex value to use. Default empty.
 *     @type string     $tabfocus_elements The previous and next element ID to move the focus to
 *                                         when pressing the Tab key in TinyMCE. Defualt ':prev,:next'.
 *     @type string     $editor_css        Intended for extra styles for both Visual and Text editors.
 *                                         Should include `<style>` tags, and can use "scoped". Default empty.
 *     @type string     $editor_class      Extra classes to add to the editor textarea elemen. Default empty.
 *     @type bool       $teeny             Whether to output the minimal editor config. Examples include
 *                                         Press This and the Comment editor. Default false.
 *     @type bool       $dfw               Whether to replace the default fullscreen with "Distraction Free
 *                                         Writing". DFW requires specific DOM elements and css). Default false.
 *     @type bool|array $tinymce           Whether to load TinyMCE. Can be used to pass settings directly to
 *                                         TinyMCE using an array. Default true.
 *     @type bool|array $quicktags         Whether to load Quicktags. Can be used to pass settings directly to
 *                                         Quicktags using an array. Default true.
 * }
 * @return array Parsed arguments array.
 */
```

You can find `wpautop` documentaton on [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpautop).